# Need to get the average of complex data on mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm not being able to find the average of a complex search in mongodb, using mongoose (nodejs) (and i'm not sure if its possible).

So, i have a collection of Scouts.
A Scout is basically the vote of a user for a player, in a match (fixture).
Scout items looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "6036dbbd148ccf17e82e6f14",
    "player": "60243968d7ec0721344514ab",
    "user": "601e9c826a339228e8f54305",
    "fixture": "602435741f2e4e263492de66",
    "score": 7,
    "text": "Lorem ipsum",
    "likes": 92,
    "createdDate": "2021-02-24T23:05:33.176Z",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "6036dbbd148ccf17e82e6f16",
    "player": "60243968d7ec0721344514ab",
    "user": "601e9c826a339228e8f54306",
    "fixture": "602435741f2e4e263492de66",
    "score": 1,
    "text": "Lorem ipsum",
    "likes": 76,
    "createdDate": "2021-02-24T23:05:33.181Z",
    "__v": 0
},
```

What i need is: the average score of a player in a fixture (among all users).
And this is what i'm trying:

```
  Scout.aggregate([
     { $match: {
        $and: [
          {player: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.playerId)},
          {fixture: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.fixtureId)},
        ]}
     },
     { $group: { _id: "$_id", "avgScore": { "$avg": "$score" }}}
   ])
```

But all i get as result is this (which is not the expected result - should be 4 as the avg):

```
{
    "_id": "6036dbbd148ccf17e82e6f16",
    "avgScore": 1
},
{
    "_id": "6036dbbd148ccf17e82e6f14",
    "avgScore": 7
}
```

]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your aggregation is okay but you are regrouping on document by `_id` which will always be different, so do this,

```
{
 $group: {
  _id: null,
  "avgScore": {
    "$avg": "$score"
  }
 }
}
```

Test it here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/6Qt8E69Z2d6

Comment: What if i want to separate the results, one line for each player and his avg? Considering i have an array of players?

Comment: At this stage if you want average for each player, try to group by player id `_id: '$player'` and you'll have your results